# Place link on whole table cell with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table created with divs only and would like to expand the link in the first cell to the whole cell area. Currently, the link is only placed on the text itself.
It is important to keep the vertical alignment of the text in the middle of the cell.

How can I make the whole cell clickable?

```css
div.divTable {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.divTable.divTable .divTableCell, .divTable.divTable {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 3px 3px;
    font-size: large;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.divTable{ display: table; }
.divTableRow { display: table-row; }
.divTableCell { display: table-cell; }
.divTableBody { display: table-row-group;}
```

```html
<div class="divTable divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">
        <a href="https://google.de">
          <div style="background-color: lightblue;">Google</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableCell">
        Dummy text line 1<br/>Dummy text line 1<br/>Dummy text line 3<br/>Dummy text line 4<br/>Dummy text line 5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making your anchor tag become `divTableCell` that is the easiest way

```css
div.divTable {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTable.divTable .divTableCell,
.divTable.divTable {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 3px 3px;
  font-size: large;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.divTable {
  display: table;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableCell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <a class="divTableCell" href="https://google.de">
        <div style="background-color: lightblue;">Google</div>
      </a>
      <div class="divTableCell">
        Dummy text line 1<br />Dummy text line 1<br />Dummy text line 3<br />Dummy text line 4<br />Dummy text line 5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```